# StructureMap Exception Code: 202 No Default Instance defined for PluginFamily

Tags: entity-framework-4, structuremap

I am Using Entity Framework 4.0 calling the below mentioned code from asp.net. I have a address table in which I need to insert some data. my code is :

```
        IRepository<Address> addressRepository;
        int addressHOCODE = 0;

        try
        {
            **addressRepository = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IRepository<Address>>();**

            addressRepository.Add(address);
            addressRepository.SaveChanges();
            addressHOCODE = address.HOCODE;
        }
        catch ...
```

At the `addressRepository = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IRepository<Address>>();` line, we're getting the following error.

> StructureMap Exception Code:  202 No
>   Default Instance defined for
>   PluginFamily
>   Domain.IRepository`1[[Data.Address,
>   DataAccessLayerNew, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]],
>   DataAccessLayerNew, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

Comment: I am missing some entries in the Global.asax. This is the reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you worked this out for yourself, but to help others who might come across this page, I'd expect to see something like this in the Global.asax.cs file:

```
using System;

namespace Host
{
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start (object sender, EventArgs e) {
            ObjectFactory.Configure(config => 
            {
                config.For<IRepository>().Use<ConcreteRepository>();
            });
        }
    }
}
```