# StructureMap Exception Code: 202\nNo Default Instance defined for PluginFamily

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, structuremap

I had given up on StructureMap a few years back or more - used Ninject and a lot of times either a project had either no IOC container, or "some" other container.

I was going to upgrade from this 2.6.x version in the project to 4.x (maybe now 5.x is out i think)

Seems like my new Service it does not like

```
    public static IContainer Initialize()
    {
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.Scan(scan =>
            {
                scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                scan.WithDefaultConventions();
            });

            x.For<INotificationService>().Use<NotificationService>();
            x.For<IMailClient>().Use<MailClient>();
            x.For<INotifierFactory>().Use<NotifierFactory>();

            x.For<ILogService>().Use<LogService>();
            x.For<IInternService>().Use<InternService>();




        });
        return ObjectFactory.Container;
    }
```

`{"StructureMap Exception Code:  202\nNo Default Instance defined for PluginFamily PublicHealth.Intern.DataAccess.Data.UnitOfWork.IInternUnitWork, PublicHealth.Intern.DataAccess.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"}`

I do see these SO references

[StructureMap Exception Code: 202 No Default Instance defined for PluginFamily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255778/structuremap-exception-code-202-no-default-instance-defined-for-pluginfamily)

[StructureMap Exception Code: 202 No Default Instance defined for PluginFamily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910493/structuremap-exception-code-202-no-default-instance-defined-for-pluginfamily)

[StructureMap Exception Code: 202 No Default Instance defined for PluginFamily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963623/structuremap-exception-code-202-no-default-instance-defined-for-pluginfamily)

I'm not sure that some of the solutions / advise will really work for me.

For example

`This problem was fixed by replacing ObjectFactory.Initialize with ObjectFactory.Configure and adding the assemblies in my project:`

:/

**I can provide more of my code if that helps.**